# EF related data dropdown list

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

I have a dropdown list which I pass to a view via a ViewBag:

```
ViewBag.RoomTypeID = new SelectList(db.RoomType, "ID", "Type");
```

This obviously works fine, but I want to do something a little more complex, and am struggling to find where to start.

Ultimately, I want the dropdown list to only show RoomTypes that haven't already been assigned (COUNT = 0) in a seperate table. My models are:

```
public class RoomType
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Room Type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Room> Rooms { get; set; }
}
```

and...

```
public class Room
{
    [Key]
    public Guid ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int PropertyID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int RoomTypeID { get; set; }

    //other properties removed for brevity

    public virtual RoomType RoomType { get; set; }

    public virtual Property Property { get; set; }
}
```

Assuming my property ID is 100, I only want to show room types in the dropdown list, where there isn't a room with propertyID 100 with the same roomtype.

What I have tried to do is this:

```
ViewBag.RoomTypeID = new SelectList(db.RoomType.Where(r => r.ID = (db.Rooms.Where(r => r.PropertyID == 1))) , "ID", "Type");
```

But I think I need to convert to a list of int's?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if i understand well, but i think you just have to refactor your linq query, like this:

```
var propertyIdNotWanted = 100;
ViewBag.RoomTypeID = new SelectList(db.RoomType.Where(r => r.Rooms.All(room => room.PropertyID != propertyIdNotWanted )) , "ID", "Type");
```

Or you could look through `Rooom` like this:

```
db.Room.Where(r => r.PropertyID != propertyIdNotWanted).Select(r => r.RoomType)
```

Comment: But the roomType entity doesn't contain PropertyID? After some additional reading, it looks like .Any may give me what i need

Comment: My bad @Gavin5511 i've updated my answer with 2 choices

Comment: Option 1 doesn't seem to compile. Error is "No overload for method 'Where' takes 3 arguments?

Comment: It was just the parenthesis, i've fixed.